# Identify unusual parts - 1x2 with a circle on the end

Tags: part-identification

I found 8 of these in a box of miscellaneous Lego but they don't have a part number on them. Anyone seen these before? Any idea what the part number might be so that I might be able to identify the set they are from? Thank you

[image: 1x2 with a circle on the end]

Answer (score 10):

Bricklink just gives them the part name [buffer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=buffer). They're for trains.

Comment: lovely thank you. train buffer! about the only thing I didn't think of!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this piece's part number is "3488" as seen on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3488/train-buffer-single/).

Comment: lovely thank you.